# How to solve "too many arguments to return" issue

Tags: go

In a print function I am writing, I am trying to return a value based on the result of a switch statement; however, I am getting the error too many arguments to return.

Forgive me if this question has a simple answer, but shouldn't it not matter how many arguments a function has and it can return just one thing? Or does it need to return one thing for each argument.

Here is my code. I am getting an error on the return line ( Too many arguments to return ). How can I fix it so that it returns the string set in the switch statement?

```
package bay

func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) {
    result := NBC(DATA, include, exclude, str)
    var sentAnal string
    switch result {
    case 1:
        sentAnal = "Strongly Negative"
    case 2:
        sentAnal = "Very Negative"
    case 3:
        sentAnal = "Negative"
    case 4:
        sentAnal = "Little Negative"
    case 5:
        sentAnal = "Neurtral"
    case 6:
        sentAnal = "Little Positive"
    case 7:
        sentAnal = "Positive"
    case 8:
        sentAnal = "More Positive"
    case 9:
        sentAnal = "Very Positive"
    case 10:
        sentAnal = "Strongly Positive"
    default:
        sentAnal = "Unknown"
    }
    return sentAnal
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in the Neurtal line should be "Neutral" :)

Comment: Should be "Neuter"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to specify what you will return after specifying the input parameters, this is not python.

This:

```
func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) {
```

Should be:

```
func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) string {
```

Recommended reads:

- http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#multiple-returns
- http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results

Or even all of [effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)

Comment: you're right. I don't think I completely switch over to the golang mind-set when I was writing this. Thank you.

Comment: I especially like the "... this is not python." addendum

Comment: :)) This Is NOT python. good one

Answer (score 4):

The signature of the method you specified does not include a return value

`func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) {`

if you want to return a string you need to add the type of the return value

`func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) string {`

Keep in mind in GO you can return multiple values

`func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) (string, string) {`

You can even give a name to the return value and reference it in your code

`func Print(DATA []TD, include string, exclude []string, str string) (sentAnal string) {`

Answer (score 3):

If you've mentioned return type as `string` then you should use `fmt.Sprintf`, not `fmt.Printf` in return statement.

Since retun type of `fmt.Printf` is `(n int, err error)` and return type of `fmt.Sprintf` is `string`.

*It doesn't answer the OP question but maybe helpful to others.*

Comment: This was indeed helpful. Thanks.