# golang too many arguments to return

Tags: go

When I assign a function to variable and try to invoke it . It throws an error 'too many arguments to return'

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  first_name := "Hello"
  last_name := "World!"
  full_name := func() {
    return first_name
  }
  fmt.Println(first_name)
  fmt.Println(last_name)
  fmt.Println(full_name)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "too many arguments to return" issue in Golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455233/how-to-solve-too-many-arguments-to-return-issue-in-golang)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your function definition to the following:

```
  full_name := func() string {
    return first_name
  }
```

That's how you tell Go that you intend to return something from a function and what that something is (a string in this case).

Then later you should call your newly created function like this:

```
   fmt.Println(full_name())
```

Comment: I think I was following this http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/basics and  it didn't have a return type :(

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare your function correctly.

```
full_name := func() string{ // add a return type
   return first_name
}
```

Even for an anonymous function, arguments and return values must be declared. Since you did not specify any return value, you cannot use `return xx`.

Also, be aware that `fmt.Println(full_name)` will return the address of the function, not execute the function. Try `fmt.Println(full_name())` instead.