# Return an AWS session object in Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

How does one return an AWS session object in golang?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
func connect(region string)   {
    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{

      // Provide SDK Config options, such as Region.
      Config: aws.Config{
        Region: &region,
      },

      SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    })
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return sess
}
```

My editor says:

```
too many arguments to return
 have (*session.Session)
 want () (build)
```

I want to be able to have the session object be created by a function and then use it in other functions.

e.x.

`func connect(region string){ return sess}`

`func getClusters(sess <don't know what object type>){ return clusters }`

`func getClusterData(sess <don't know what type>, clusters []string){return output}`

I'm used to doing this in python, so I'm still trying to grasp the concepts.

I searched on google for things like:

- return aws session object golang
- golang return aws session from function
- golang return session object

Comment: Declare a return value: `func connect(region string)   *session.Session { ... }`.  See [How to solve “too many arguments to return” issue in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455233/how-to-solve-too-many-arguments-to-return-issue-in-golang) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+too+many+arguments+to+return).

Comment: Also, I would avoid calling that function `connect() `, since it's not connecting to anything, but rather setting up a Session object, which simply carries information required for the SDK to create requests.